# Override Devise Invitable `invite!` method in order to add attachment to invitation email - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, actionmailer

I have `devise_invitable` gem and an invitations controller `InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController`. I invite my user with this method `User.invite!(user, inviter)` from the gem.

Now, I would like to add pdf attachment to this invitation but I am not able to override the mailer method in order to do stuff like this: `attachments['terms.pdf'] = File.read('/path/terms.pdf')`.

My invitation email is working fine and I would like to keep it like that but with an attachment.

Here my `routes.rb`:

```rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'api/v1/users/invitations' }
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeviseInvitable has a usefull `skip_invitation` option.
With the following method you can easily use your own mailer and add attachment in it :

```
def invite_and_notify_user(email)
  user = User.invite!({ email: email }) do |u|
    u.skip_invitation = true
  end
  notify_by_email(user)
end


def notify_by_email(user)
  MyUserMailer.invited_user_email(user).deliver
end
```

In MyUserMailer class:

```
  def invited_user_email(user)
    @user = user
    attachments['terms.pdf'] = File.read('/path/terms.pdf')
    mail(to: user.email, from: 'contact@mail.com', subject: "Your subject")
  end
```

Comment: Thanks @emilie it works, but I have to pass the `raw_invitation_token` (as the doc suggests ) to my mailer in order to update invitation from the `invitations_controller`.

You can also skip invitation like this : `user = User.invite!(email: email, skip_invitation: true)`, it's shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the devise mailer like so...

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
  # If there is an object in your application that returns a contact email, you can use it as follows
  # Note that Devise passes a Devise::Mailer object to your proc, hence the parameter throwaway (*).
  default from: ->(*) { Class.instance.email_address }
end
```

You can then  in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, set `config.mailer` to "MyMailer". Note that this overrides the mailer used for all devise modules.

Then in that class add your attachment to invited_user_instructions...

```
def invited_user_instructions(*args)
  attachments['terms.pdf'] = File.read('/path/terms/pdf')
  super
end
```

This is devise's instructions https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer